# converting numeric value to String in SQLITE

Tags: sqlite, type-conversion

I have tried to convert numeric  value into string datatype in SQLITE.
While changing numeric (Int, float, Real)into string i got like this..

Ex: 2016    ,    2016.12
output : 2016.0     , 2016.12

Expected Result: 2016 ,201612

My Code for conversion

```
CAST(`mega-join-Ex-v1`.`Annee` AS STRING)
```

Please any one suggest correct method to convert numeric into string type.

Comment: Why did you expect the numeric value 2016.12 to become the string 201612?

Comment: Try casting **and** replacing the decimals

Comment: I need to convert 2016(numeric) into 2016(string) format. But I got result like 2016.0 .How to remove this unwanted .0 from the string.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I have added that lines by mistake(2016.12->201612). My question is If I convert any numeric(without decimal) values to string in SQLite , it will show result with decimal point(.0)                                                               
   Ex:  2016-> 2016.0

Comment: You have to explain what you're doing more clearly.  If you run "select  cast(2016 as text), typeof(cast(2016 as text));" you get the expected "2016|text".  Note that STRING is not a type in SQLite3.  If you *do* use STRING instead of TEXT, "select  cast(2016 as string), typeof(cast(2016 as string));" you will get "2016|integer".